# How to get the row which having same values on a specific column in MySql?

Tags: mysql

I'm have a table with following structure and data. I would like to get the conversation_id of a row that having given user_id(s).
For example. I would like to get the **conversation_id** between **user_id 1** and **user 2**, so the result should be **1**. If I would like to get the **conversation_id** of **user_id 1 to 4**, the result should be **4**.
How could I write in sql query? [image: table structure]

Comment: Join the table with itself.

Comment: The joining relationship should be the conversation ID. Then the two instances of the table should be filtered to the two user IDs you want the conversation between.

Answer (score 0):

You can `GROUP BY conversation_id` and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT conversation_id
FROM tablename
WHERE user_id IN (1, 2) -- the ids of the users 
GROUP BY conversation_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) = 2 -- the number of the users
```